# incorrect integer value '' for column cuit at row 1

Tags: sql, delphi

I have a webservice, with the next code in the implementation:

```
procedure Tferreteria.inserpersona(persona:Tpersona);
begin
  //insertar persona
  dm:=Tconsultas.Create(nil);

   with dm.SQLQuery1 do
   begin
     Close;
     SQL.Add('insert into persona (nombreyape, domicilio)values (:nombreyape,:domicilio);');
     ParamByName('nombreyape').AsString:=persona.nombreyape;
     ParamByName('domicilio').AsString:=persona.domicilio;
     ExecSQL();
   end;
 end;

 procedure Tferreteria.insercliente(cliente:Tcliente);
 begin
   //insertar cliente

   with dm.SQLQuery1 do
   begin
     SQL.Clear;
     SQL.Add ('insert into clientes(idcliente,idpersona,cuit,cuil) values (null,(select     last_insert_id()),:cuit,:cuil);');

     ParamByName('cuit').AsInteger:=cliente.cuit;
     ParamByName('cuil').AsInteger:=cliente.cuil;
     ExecSQL();
   end;
 end;
```

As you see are 2 procedures which insert into tables personas and clientes. Clientes have a column idpersona which references personas

In the button click event I have this code

```
with Persona do
begin
  nombreyape:=Form2.Edit1.Text;
  domicilio:=Form2.Edit8.Text;
  idlocalidad:=StrToInt(Form2.Edit3.Text);
end;

with Cliente do
begin
  cuit:=StrToInt(Edit6.Text);
  cuil:=StrToInt(Edit7.Text);
end;
//llamar al servicio
GetIferreteria.inserpersona(Persona);
GetIferreteria.insercliente(Cliente);
```

and I obtain this error

> incorrect integer value 'aaa' for column cuit at row 1,

when aaa is written in edit1, which is not assigned to clientes.cuit,

---

Now I have another problem:

I have to insert idpersona in clientes, but I have to insert idpersona in telper, telper is a table which makes a relation among telephones and people who have these telephones.

If I do the same with other query, the last insert id would be an id from clientes (idcliente), not idpersona.

What can I do to make the idpersona stand for each moment I need to use it, in each table I mean?

Comment: How can you hope to succeed without naming anything. You cannot really be using Edit6 etc. Surely not.

Comment: You need to validate inputdata before sending it towards your webservice. Using a TMaskEdit control will help to prevent end user input errors.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you re-write this code.  Especially since you are using `last_insert_id()` (which you do not need to `select` to retreive), so you should execute the two statements together, preferably in a transaction (or better, in a stored procedure).

Try something more like this:

```
procedure Tferreteria.inserPersonaUnCliente(persona: Tpersona; cliente: Tcliente);
var
  Query: TSQLQuery;
  Conn: TSQLConnection;
  SQL: TStrings;
  Trans: TDBXTransaction;
begin
  dm := Tconsultas.Create(nil);
  Query := dm.SQLQuery1;
  Conn := Query.SQLConnection;
  SQL := Query.SQL;

  //insertar persona un cliente

  Query.Close;

  Trans := Conn.BeginTransaction;
  try
    SQL.BeginUpdate;
    try
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('insert into persona (nombreyape, domicilio) values (:nombreyape, :domicilio);';
      SQL.Add('insert into clientes(idcliente, idpersona, cuit, cuil) values (null, last_insert_id(), :cuit, :cuil);');
    finally
      SQL.EndUpdate;
    end;
    Query.ParamByName('nombreyape').AsString := persona.nombreyape;
    Query.ParamByName('domicilio').AsString := persona.domicilio;
    Query.ParamByName('cuit').AsInteger := cliente.cuit;
    Query.ParamByName('cuil').AsInteger := cliente.cuil;
    Query.ExecSQL;
    Conn.CommitFreeAndNil(Trans);
  except
    Conn.RollbackFreeAndNil(Trans);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

```
with Persona do
begin
  nombreyape := Form2.Edit1.Text;
  domicilio := Form2.Edit8.Text;
  idlocalidad := StrToInt(Form2.Edit3.Text);
end;

with Cliente do
begin
  cuit := StrToInt(Edit6.Text);
  cuil := StrToInt(Edit7.Text);
end;

//llamar al servicio
GetIferreteria.inserPersonaUnCliente(Persona, Cliente);
```

Comment: It says "You have an error in your sql sintax" in the second statement, in insert into clientes... and in my database in the table persona there is not new row. Sorry..

Comment: If it is complaining about a syntax error, it should also be telling you what is actually wrong with the syntax. The only thing I changed from the syntax of your original statement was to change `select last_insert_id()` to just `last_insert_id()`, so try changing that back.